# CheckBox issue in DocuSign Tab

Tags: c#, checkbox, docusignapi

When I add checkbox to Tab I see double check box on my pdf.

```
checkbox= new CheckBox(){TabLable="Large",Selected="true",Locked="true",DocumentId="1",PageNumber="1",XPosition="328",YPosition="362"};
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you change your photo to screenshot will be better to see and edit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your original document has a checkbox on it and you're adding a second one via DocuSign.

To debug further, use [DocuSign logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see exactly what you're sending to DocuSign. If your API request has one checkbox then that is what DocuSign will add to the document.

(Unless you're using anchor text position which can add multiple tabs on the document with one specification in the API call.)

### Added

To convert a PDF that has PDF form fields in it, use the PDF Form Field Transformation feature. See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs#pdftransform).

Comment: Yes My pdf have fields. But After creating envelop for second signer it seems perfect. What is the best way to fill pdf fields by docusign. Please suggest any code.